# .csv file is returning a "unicode error" when I attempt to import in python

Tags: pandas, csv, python-import

I am attempting to import a .csv dataset file using pandas on Jupyter notebook. I keep receiving the same "unicode decode error" message

I've tried with and without `(r'file name')` and doubling up on backslashes, as well as using forward slashes

this is my code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\users\justanotheregg\Downloads\medals.csv')
```

this is part of what I am receiving

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 12: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Comment: You should add encoding parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSV file is apparently not in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) format, but that is what the function expects by default. You need to find out what encoding the file is in (if it is an Excel export, it's probably 'cp-1252'; the other likely encodings, from the ISO-8859 family, don't have a mapping for 0x92, where it's the closing single quote `’` in 1252, very common in text written in MS Office) and [pass its name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) as the [optional encoding parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Just saved it to google sheets and then downloaded the same file and the panda read it in jupyter notebook ok.